# Junit java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.reward"

Tags: java, junit

I have a test method that is provided,

```
@Test
    public void calculateReward() throws Exception {

        when(userService.findById(any(Long.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));
        int steps = 1000;

        user.setCurrentSteps(steps);
        user.setTotalSteps(steps);

        when(userService.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(user);
        Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("EUR", 1.0);
        when(currencyUtilities.getCurrencyMap()).thenReturn(map);

        mockMvc.perform(put("/api/v1/users/calculateReward")
                .param("userId", String.valueOf(user.getId())))
                .andExpect(
                        status().isCreated()
                ).andExpect(
                content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        ).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(
                        jsonPath("$.name", is(user.getName()))
                ).andExpect(
                jsonPath("$.currency", is(user.getCurrencyName()))
        ).andExpect(
                jsonPath("$.reward", is(1.0)));
    }
```

I get the error message,

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.reward"
Expected: is <1.0>
     but: was "1.00"
Expected :is <1.0>
Actual   :"1.00"
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the error message says: the test expects to see the number 1.0 in the JSON it receives (`is(1.0)`), but the JSON actually contained the string `"1.00"` at that path. Read https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath for the meaning of paths, but `$.reward` is just the `"reward"` field of the root object. So it should look like

```
{
  "reward": 1.0,
  ... other fields including "name" and "currency"
}
```

but was

```
{
  "reward": "1.00",
  ...
}
```

Comment: How do I correct it? Sorry if its dumb, but I am not able to. Changing ti to the `jsonPath("$.reward", is(1.00)));` doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: `is("1.00")`. But first you need to figure out whether it's the test or the system you are testing which should be corrected! Especially since you say the test is "provided".